# Question about two definitions of isomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

The first definition is common: 
A linear transformation I : $\mathbb{X}$ → $\mathbb{Y}$ is called an isomorphism if it is both onto and one-to-one.

The second definition is:
$(\mathbb{X},||\cdot||_{\mathbb{X}})$ and $(\mathbb{Y},||\cdot||_{\mathbb{Y}})$ are normed linear spaces.
A linear map I from $(\mathbb{X},||\cdot||_{\mathbb{X}})$ onto  $(\mathbb{Y},||\cdot||_{\mathbb{Y}})$ is isomorphism if
$$\exists m,M>0,s.t. m||x||_{\mathbb{X}}\leq ||Ix||_{\mathbb{Y}}\leq M||x||_{\mathbb{X}}$$
I don't know how to prove isomorphism is one-to-one in the second definition.

Comment: Dont mix symbolic notation ($\exists m,M$ and "s.t.") And definitely don't remove $\forall x.$ As in, $\exists m,M\forall x\in \mathbb X...$

Comment: It doesn't seem possible to prove the second sort of isomorphism is onto. $1-1$ yes, but not onto.

Answer (score 3):

If $Ix = Iy$, then since $I$ is linear, we have $I(x - y) = 0$, or we have that $m\|x - y\|_{\mathbb{X}} \le \|0\|_{\mathbb{Y}} = 0 \implies x = y$.